# Cut and Copy in Ubuntu Command line

Tags: command-line, clipboard

How Could i copy or cut a file from a directory to another directory?

I mean in command line!

Comment: You might also want to look at their man pages [Copy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/cp.1.html)  and [Move](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mv.1.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple: type in terminal

## For copy

```
cp /PATH1/file [file2 file3 ...] /PATH2/[newfilename or noting to use the same name]
```

*and* for more info about `cp` use `man cp`

---

## For cut(move and rename)

```
mv /PATH1/file /PATH2/[newfilename or noting to use the same name]
```

*and* for more info about `mv` use `man mv`

Comment: thank you!

   but i have to use just `mv` and `cp`?

   `copy` and `move` didn`t work?

Comment: you @MiladSobhkhiz can use copy and move too, depending in what os you are using....

Comment: He said, he is using Ubuntu

Comment: The correct commands are mv and cp. You can create alias if you want and make copy respond to cp for example.

Answer (score 6):

Hi here we go with a practical example:

```
1. Copy 

    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ mkdir copy
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ mkdir move
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ touch file1 file2 file3 file4
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ cp file1 copy
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ ls copy
    file1

2. Move


    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ ls
    copy  file1  file2  file3  file4  move
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ mv file2 move
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ ls move
    file2
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ ls
    copy  file1  file3  file4  move


3. Rename

    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ mv file3 file2
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$ ls
    copy  file1  file2  file4  move
    raja@badfox:~/Folder$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my view of it. You want to move file1 from dir1 to file2 in dir2, So here is how:
`mv /PATH/TO/FILE1/ /PATH/TO/FILE2/`
practical example:
~/Documents$ `ls
text.txt

cd ..
cd Desktop
ls

cd ..
mv ~/Documents/text.txt/ ~/Desktop/text.txt
cd Desktop
ls

text.txt`

Hope it helps and isn't too complicated :D